# Present View above keyboard in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, user-interface, swiftui

I'd like to be able to present a view the is aligned to the bottom of the top of the keyboard regardless of the device. I'm trying to use strictly SwiftUI for this as I don't know UIKit. I have attached the picture of said solution.

Can someone show me a coded solution that would work in SwiftUI to achieve this basic result? Thanks.

I have used the `.toolbar` modifier to hack the result I wanted with a custom view. Still wondering if there are other solutions that may work cleaner since it isn't how it's intended to be used.

[image: Google Tasks application screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Just create a `ToolbarItem` on the `.keyboard`.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = "Hello world!"

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Text", text: $text)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Text("Keyboard item")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: I actually have figured that out as one solution, but how do you modify the size of the toolbar so that it fit's more than a single row of items like the screenshot I presented?

Comment: @JustinComstock You can put whatever you want in place of the `Text`, like a `VStack` containing your content.